# get whole location header value of response in Jsoup

Tags: java, http-headers, jsoup

I want to get location header from response. I am using Jsoup for this.
Below code I am using.

```
        Response loginFormFirst = Jsoup.connect("https://myurl.com/admin/login/auth/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0")
                .header("Accept-Language", "text/html")
                .followRedirects(false)
                .execute();
```

With this I am able to get Location header value - https://myurl.com/admin/auth/login/
But this is not same as in network tab of browser.
I want Location header value as displayed in network tab of browser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you are using Jsoup and you want to retrieve the html code of your web you should retrieve a Document containing the HTML code of your web (including scripts or PHP).

The way to retrieve the Document is:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://myurl.com/admin/login/auth/")
                         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                         .get();
```

And if you want to retrieve the HTML parsed as String you should use:

```
String parsedHtml = Jsoup.connect("https://myurl.com/admin/login/auth/")
                         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                         .get()
                         .html();
```

Hope it helps!